# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body Code : 50035 , Slash commands

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hello So I was developing my own slash command handler for the Discord.js v13 bot
But I have run into a snag.... When I collect the array of all slash commands and their respective options to register into the commands.set() method I get an error which is :

```
**>  throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
>             ^
> 
> DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body options[2]: Required options must
> be placed before non-required options
>     at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
> 
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
>     at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
>     at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:146:18)
>     at async Object.execute (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\slashregistering.js:71:13) {   method:
> 'put',   path:
> '/applications/922152514420363285/guilds/933052184432636014/commands',
> code: 50035,   httpStatus: 400,**
```

This is the complete code of the slashregistering.js ( pls ignore the code typing style... )

```
**const fs = require('fs')
const db= require('quick.db')


module.exports = {
    async execute(client){
        const categories = ['MODERATION' , 'FUN' ,'ACTIONS' , 'UTILITY']
        const registeredCommandsArray = new Array()
        const guildId = '933052184432636014'
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
        //console.log(client.guilds.cache);
        let commands 
        var commandsarray = new Array()
        
        if(guild){
            commands = guild.commands
        } 
        else{
            commands = client.application?.commands
        }
        //console.log(commands)
        let data 
        data = await db.get('slashcommands')
        
        if(data){
            var scommands = new Array() 
            var unRegisteredCommands
            const slashcommands = await guild.commands.fetch()
            unRegisteredCommands = slashcommands.filter(a => !data.includes(a.name))

            for(var e in unRegisteredCommands){
                scommands.push(e.name)
            }

            for(const category of categories){
                
                for(const file of scommands){
                    const command = require(`./slashcommands/${category}/${file}.js`)
                    //console.log(command , category)
                    commandsarray.push({
                        name : command.name,
                        description : command.description,
                        options : command.options
                    })
                    
                }
            }
            data.concat(scommands)
            //console.log(data)
            commands.set(commandsarray)
            console.log(`Loaded ${scommands.length} commands.`)
            await db.set('slashcommands' , data)


        }
        else{
            for(const category of categories){
                const slashCommandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./slashcommands/${category}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
                for(const file of slashCommandFiles){
                    const command = require(`./slashcommands/${category}/${file}`)
                    //console.log(command , category)
                    commandsarray.push({
                        name : command.name,
                        description : command.description,
                        options : command.options
                    })
                    registeredCommandsArray.push(command.name)
                }
            }
            console.log(`Loaded ${registeredCommandsArray.length} commands.`)
            await commands.set(commandsarray)
            await db.set('slashcommands' , registeredCommandsArray)
            
            

        }
    }
}**
```

Its all working fine until I reach the commands.set(commandsarray) ... Please help ! and thanks in advance!

Comment: all required options must be at the start, you are putting a non-required option before a required option

Comment: @MrMythical Oh okay thanks for telling could you please  tell me where I can find the required options and non-required ones? Because the YT vid that I used as a reference used the three options only : name , description and options.....